# "Change", "exchange" and "trade"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

In a scenario I came across a sentence and tried to translated it to English. I am interested to know which one of the similar verbs listed below work here properly?

I wouldn’t............being in the loving embrace of the family over anything.

> a) [trade](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trade)
>
> b) [exchange](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/exchange)
>
> c) change

For me, excepting the last one the first two sound the same and natural, but what a native speaker would think.

Comment: Usually one trades *for*, exchanges *for*, change (in this case) *for*, not "over." Beautiful sentiment, by the way. And, does the original mean "the family" or "my family"?

Comment: @MarkH - I think the original could leave the article out altogether: _I wouldn’t trade being in the loving embrace of family for anything_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern for this idiom you are looking for is

> trade *something* for *something else*
>   I wouldn't *trade being with you for the world.*

"Exchange" is usually not used.

> I wouldn't change a thing.

is another way to express the *not trading* sentiment in your first sentence.

Comment: So what is the best choice here @Peter? :)

Comment: Wouldn't trade **X** for **Y**. I wouldn't trade **this** for **all the money in the world**. "I wouldn't trade being in the loving embrace of **a** family over anything."

Comment: The question is specifically asking to focus on trade/exchange/change and you seem to be emphasizing (based on your bold/italics) on the rest of the sentence.

Comment: I'm showing the usual pattern that is used, which is a contrast.

Comment: I got your point. Thank you both @Catija and Peter. :)